# How is Spring Boot HazelcastHealthIndicator configured and accessed using http?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am trying to check the health of a Hazelcast member using Spring's HazelcastHealthIndicator and actuator, any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Spring will automatically adds Hazelcast health information into `/health` endpoint. You just need to add below property to see all the details in /health endpoint.

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

sample `/actuator/health` endpoint output follows, For reference look at `HazelcastHealthContributorAutoConfiguration` class.

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "H2",
        "result": 1,
        "validationQuery": "SELECT 1"
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 255850758144,
        "free": 69382373376,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "hazelcast": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "name": "hazelcast-instance",
        "uuid": "be259156-a72c-4b26-a2f2-667e9de7bf5c"
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a setup with Hazelcast but in general Health Indicators are designed to provide the information about the health of the system in the actuator's `/health` method.

System health is a "composite" notion.

For example:

Lets say, the application has many components: Hazelcast, Cassandra, Elasticsearch. So you might want to consider the application as "healthy" (read `/health` will return status 200) only if all these components are healthy.

So there are 3 `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator` interface's implementations, one of which is the Hazelcast Health Indicator that you've mentioned in the question.

If you invoke the `/health` endpoint and see that there is no information about Hazelcast, there might be permission issue (make sure you've read [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints))